# Can't build project with minSdk = 21

Tags: android, gradle, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm succesfully building the project with min sdks up to 20, but when i try to build with:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 21
```

I get an error:

```
:project:preDexDebug
no classfiles specified

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/user/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/21.1.1/dx -JXmx2g --dex --multi-dex --output /Users/user/Project-Android/project/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/tween-engine-api-sources-a613effab3e9735b093029491b18c5c4872bdf88.jar /Users/user/Project-Android/project/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android-ui-client.gdxlibrary/android/unspecified/libs/tween-engine-api-sources.jar
Error Code:
1
Output:
no classfiles specified
```

I'm using libgdx in some places of the app.

Then the install dialog apears and if I choose a device I get another error:

```
Target device: genymotion-google_nexus_6___5_0_0___api_21___1440x2560-192.168.56.103:5555
Uploading file
    local path: /Users/user/Project-Android/project/build/outputs/apk/project-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.ui.client.debug
I/O Error: /Users/user/Project-Android/project/build/outputs/apk/project-debug.apk (No such file or directory)
```

And then an IDE dialog apears with error message:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
```

(just empty space after cause)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: Did you find the reason ? I have similar problem. I enabled multidex in my app and now build is far too slow so I need to build with a 'dev' flavor with minSdkVersion 21 (it was ok with previous minSdkVersion value)
But now it fails with:
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"no classfiles specified","position":{},"original":"no classfiles specified"}

Execution failed for task ':preDexDevDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'java' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: I've revisited it and set
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion =  "23.0.1" and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. After running gradle with --debug option it turned out that gradle failed to process a jar file with no class files in it (a *-javadoc.jar).

Removing the file from /libs folder fixed the issue.

Comment: This will also happen if you're referencing AARs without and classes in them (i.e. just resources).